# Javascript function call doesn't return after asynchronous xhttp database access

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

The function doesn't return at all, so the code that follows it doesn't run. What am I missing as far as asynchronous xmlhttp requests are concerned?
The function is as below. The console will display "Done 1" and "Done 2" but not "Done 3"

```js
function _getInventory() {
    //This function
    console.log("The function is running");
    var xmlhttpr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttpr.responseType = "document";
    xmlhttpr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {//The request was fulfilled
            var xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
            console.log(xmlDoc);
            var returnStatus = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("status")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            if(returnStatus==0) {//Results were found
                //get an itemNodeList object
                itemNodeListr = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Items")[0].getElementsByTagName("Item");
                //Purge the 'html' variable of previous search data
                var invDisplay = document.getElementById("inventory-display");
                var html = "<div class='item-slide' onclick='javascript:add_to_inventory()' id='edit-inv-data'>";
                html+="<img src='../icons/add.png'>"
                html+="</div>"; //APPROPRIATE ID
                invDisplay.innerHTML=html;

                if(itemNodeListr.length>0) {
                    var i = 0;
                    var html="";
                    for(i=0;i<itemNodeListr.length; i++) {
                        html="<div class='item-slide'>";
                        html+="<div class='item-slide-image'>";
                        html+="<img src='"+getValue(itemNodeListr, i, 'ImageURI')+"'>";
                        html+="</div><!--item-slide-header-->"
                        html+="<div class='item-slide-content' id='itemid"+i+"'>"
                        html+="<table>";
                        html+="<tr>";
                        html+="<th>Name</th>";
                        html+="<td>"+getValue(itemNodeListr, i, 'ItemName')+"</td>";
                        html+="</tr>";
                        html+="<tr>";
                        html+="<th>Other Names</th>";
                        html+="<td>"+getValue(itemNodeListr, i, 'Aliases')+"</td>";
                        html+="</tr>";
                        html+="<tr>";
                        html+="<th>Description</th>";
                        html+="<td>"+getValue(itemNodeListr, i, 'Description')+"</td>";
                        html+="</tr>";
                        html+="<tr>";
                        html+="<th>Quantity</th>";
                        html+="<td>"+getValue(itemNodeListr, i, 'Quantity')+" "+getValue(itemNodeListr, i, 'Units')+"</td>";
                        html+="</tr>";
                        html+="<tr>";
                        html+="<th>Unit Price</th>";
                        html+="<td>"+getValue(itemNodeListr, i, 'UnitPrice')+"</td>";
                        html+="</tr>";
                        html+="<tr>";
                        html+="<th>State</th>";
                        html+="<td>"+getValue(itemNodeListr, i, 'State')+"</td>";
                        html+="</tr>";
                        html+="<tr>";
                        html+="<th>Description</th>";
                        html+="<td>"+getValue(itemNodeListr, i, 'Description')+"</td>";
                        html+="</tr>";
                        html+="<tr>";
                        html+="<th>Added On</th>";
                        html+="<td>"+getValue(itemNodeListr, i, 'DateAdded')+"</td>";
                        html+="</tr>";
                        html+="<th>Can Deliver? (Y/N) </th>";
                        html+="<td>"+getValue(itemNodeListr, i, 'Deliverable')+"</td>";
                        html+="</tr>";
                        html+="<th>Can Deliver To: </th>";
                        html+="<td>"+getValue(itemNodeListr, i, 'DeliverableAreas')+"</td>";
                        html+="</tr>";
                        html+="</table>";
                        html+="</div><!--item-slide-header-->"
                        html+="<div id='addToRep'>";//ID means 'Add to repository'
                        html+="<button onclick='void(0)'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit</button>";
                        html+="</div>";
                        html+="<span onclick='rem_rep_item("+i+")' id='rem-rep-item"+i+"' class='close' title='Delete Item'>×</span>";
                        html+="</div>";
                        document.getElementById("inventory-display").innerHTML+=html;
                    }
                    console.log("Done 1");
                }

            } else if(returnStatus==1) {//No Results found
                console.log("No results were found");
            } else if(returnStatus==3) {//Problem connecting to the database
                console.log("There was a problem connecting to the database");
            } else if(returnStatus==11) {//User is not logged in. Not even sure how that's possible
                console.log("WTF? Is that even possible");
            }
        } else {//The request wasn't fulfilled for some reason
            console.log("ReadyState = "+this.readyState);
            console.log("Status = "+this.status)
        }
        console.log("Done 2");
    }
    xmlhttpr.open("GET", "xhttp.php?table=Repository", true);
    xmlhttpr.send();
    console.log("Done 3");
}
```

Comment: There is no reason it should not proceed to the end of the function and print Done 3. By the way, you should really find another way to create that HTML other than dozens of string assignment statements.

Comment: I just ran it and it most definitely does log "Done 3". It should so long as you are calling `_getInventory()` and no errors are thrown before that line is reached. Do you mean that it doesn't log "Done 1"? That would be caused by the request failing (e.g. running this when you are offline).

Comment: You guys were right on one thing: "Done 3" is displayed, but that didn't solve the problem. In the code, when I call
`_getInventory(); //Followed by `
`console.log('The function returned');  //This doesn't run!`

Comment: The web page is successfully updated and the console looks like;
`The function is running
index.js:163 ReadyState = 1
index.js:164 Status = 0
index.js:166 Done 2
index.js:169 Done 2.5
index.js:171 Done 3
index.js:163 ReadyState = 2
index.js:164 Status = 200
index.js:166 Done 2
index.js:163 ReadyState = 3
index.js:164 Status = 200
index.js:166 Done 2
index.js:83 #document
index.js:152 Done 1
index.js:166 Done 2`

Comment: I'm sorry for the formatting! The comment section seems to ignore new line characters. I'd be mad if I had to read that!!
And @torazaburo, I'd really appreciate a better suggestion! I also find this a little... unclean.